# Lubuntu LiveCD disabling auto-mount.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, livecd, pxe

In cooperation with my IT teacher we want to boot all PC's in IT class with Lubuntu. I've successfully set up PXE server, but there is one thing that worries us. Harddrives shouldn't be accessible from booted Lubuntu(normal user only). Would adding to fstab something like:

```
/dev/sda1 /Idk/What auto noauto
```

work? I'd like to add that I can uncompress squashfs livecd filesystem. If no, what other solution is there, to block auto-mounting /dev/sda drive?

Comment: Why are you using Live sessions for this? Why not actually install? Anyway, the local disk is not mounted by default on a live session, it needs to be mounted manually.

Comment: Well actually it mounts available partitions in /media/ubuntu dir. I can't install Lubuntu on those PC's because there are new Windows licences bla bla bla... Can't be done yet.
Any other suggestions? I really would like to disable that auto mounting in Thunar...

Comment: Wow, OK, haven't seen that, it may be specific to the Ubuntu session. Have you tried other live CDs? Also, how does the Windows license stop you from installing a dual boot system? You really don't want a live session here since the default user will always have root privileges through `sudo`. At least, that's the case when booting from a live CD on the actual computer and I don't see why PXE would change that.

Comment: I have edited /etc/sudoers file so that live user shouldn't have root access. Installing dualboot would most problably mean resizing Windows partition, which in some cases may fail, and my IT teacher seems to be too lazy to reinstall windows there. I am following archwiki's guide of remastering the iso to modifie Xubuntu live cd... hope it will work. I know I've sad Lubuntu before, I meant Xubuntu. No big differece there.

Comment: In that case, in principle simply adding the `noauto` to `fstab` should be enough. Could you [edit] your question to include the default `fstab` entry that mounts the drives in `/media/ubuntu`?

Comment: @terdon: in /etc/fstab in xubuntu filesystem.squashfs all that there is :
"# UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM"
I can't find any config file for automounting available partitions...

Comment: Hang on, I think I understand what you mean now, the partitions are not automatically mounted, you mean that a user can click on them in the GUI file manager and _that_ will mount them right? I strongly urge you to install though. Resizing the windows partition should not be a problem (I have done this dozens of times and never had an issue) and there is absolutely no reason to reinstall windows after the resize.

Comment: @terdon: ok, I guess we will try it, but first I need to do some reading about LDAP. Until then, is there a way to disable that click-to-mount option? I've added setting chmod on /dev/sd* devices to 000 in rc.local, but still it's possible for user to mount them in RW... :(